# I'm Getting error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: while running a python code

Tags: python-requests, data-extraction

I have got this code from internet, for extracting data from justdial website.

While running this code I got the following error:

```
ERROR:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) is shown.
```

Please help me to run this code as i'm not familiar with python. What changes should be done to run this code step by step.
Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print(25*"=")
print("Just Dial Scraper")
print(25*"=")

url = 'http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act'\
      '=pagination&city={0}&search={1}&page={2}'
what = input("Enter your Query: ")
what = what.replace(' ', '+')
where = input("Enter the Location: ")

with open(what+"_"+where+'.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('company, address, phone\n')
    page = 1
    while True:
        print('Scraping Page', page)
        resp = requests.get(url.format(where, what, page))

    if not resp.json()['paidDocIds']:
        print(25*"-")
        print('Scraping Finished')
        print(25*"-")
        break

    markup = resp.json()['markup'].replace('\/', '/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')

    for thing in soup.find_all('section'):
        csv_list = []
        if thing.get('class') == ['jcar']:
            # Company name
            for a_tag in thing.find_all('a'):
                if a_tag.get('onclick') == "_ct('clntnm', 'lspg');":
                    csv_list.append(a_tag.get('title'))

            # Address
            for span_tag in thing.find_all('span'):
                if span_tag.get('class') == ['mrehover', 'dn']:
                    csv_list.append(span_tag.get_text().strip())

            # Phone number
            for a_tag in thing.find_all('a'):
                if a_tag.get('href').startswith('tel:'):
                    csv_list.append(a_tag.get('href').split(':')[-1])

            csv_list = ['"'+item+'"' for item in csv_list]
            writeline = ','.join(csv_list)+'\n'
            f.write(','.join(csv_list)+'\n')
    page += 1
```

Comment: First thing to check would be that the URL you're hitting is actually returning content.  By that error message I would guess that it's not.

Comment: yes you are right ..url does not return any content..but still it gives the same error while running with url https://www.justdial.com/ ..Or else am i doing it wrong..? @Rick Riensche